# iOS 8 - Text in UITextField disappear when scrolling the UITableview

Tags: uitableview, ios8

I have a plus button, which when clicked , creates 2 rows with a header in a UITableview and each row has a UILabel and a UITextfield. And this process goes on , the number of times you click the plus button. My problem is that , if I enter some text in UITextfield and scrolls the table view up or down, its text disappears.

Here is the code which i have, but no code is there how to save UITextfield data (because i don't know what i suppose to do).

```
- (IBAction)addCycles:(id)sender {
    [sectionsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cycle %d",[sectionsArray count]+1]];
    [rowsInSectionArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d",[rowsInSectionArray count]]];
    [tablesForCycles reloadData];
}

#pragma mark Table View data source and delegate

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [sectionsArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 2;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [sectionsArray objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            chemoDateLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 9, 100, 40)];
            cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    }
    [chemoDateLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:9]];
    NSArray *cellLabelsText=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Chemo Date",@"Chemo Agent", nil];
    cell.textLabel.text=[cellLabelsText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        chemoDateTF=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 11, 160, 25)];
        chemoDateTF.delegate=self;
        [chemoDateTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        [cell addSubview:chemoDateTF];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
        chemoDateTF.inputView=datePickerForCell;
    }else if (indexPath.row==1){
        chemoAgentTF=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 11, 160, 25)];
        chemoAgentTF.delegate=self;
        [chemoAgentTF setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
        [cell addSubview:chemoAgentTF];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    }
    return cell;
}
```